Why does using INSERT INTO calls in Snowflake SQL generate an error when included in a stored procedure?
I have a table in snowflake which shows for a given table and date, the number of unique primary keys associated with it. Here is some sample data
create table salesforce.unprocessed.job_logs2 (namespace varchar(255), rundate datetime, distinct_count NUMBER);

insert into  salesforce.unprocessed.job_logs2 (namespace, rundate, distinct_count)
values
('SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.ACCOUNTTEAMMEMBER', '2024-11-01', 12345),
('SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.ACCOUNTTEAMMEMBER', '2024-11-02', 12346),
('SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.ACCOUNTTEAMMEMBER', '2024-11-03', 12347),
('SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.USERROLE', '2024-11-01', 15),
('SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.USERROLE', '2024-11-01', 19),
('SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.USERROLE', '2024-11-01', 19)

What I am trying to accomplish is have a daily job which runs a query against these tables in salesforce.unprocessed in order to count the number of unique ids. I have created the following stored procedure to perform this insertion for me (I'll create a task afterwards to run it), but I'm getting an error
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_daily_job()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
namespaces ARRAY;
namespace VARCHAR;
result VARCHAR;
BEGIN
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(namespace) INTO :namespaces FROM namespaces_table;
FOR namespace IN :namespaces LOOP
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO salesforce.unprocessed.job_logs
    SELECT :namespace AS namespace, CURRENT_DATE() AS rundate,
           (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM IDENTIFIER($namespace$)) AS distinct_id_count,
           (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM IDENTIFIER($namespace$)) AS id_count;
    result := 'Success';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      result := 'Error processing namespace: ' || :namespace || ' - ' || SQLERRM();
  END;
END LOOP;
RETURN result;
END;
$$;



But I'm getting an error that I don't understand how to deal with
Syntax error: unexpected 'INTO'. (line 10)

syntax error line 10 at position 26 unexpected '.'.
syntax error line 10 at position 38 unexpected '.'.
syntax error line 11 at position 4 unexpected 'SELECT'. (line 10)

Can someone explain to me what the problem is here? I don't understand it. It looks to me like this should run.
Note: the namespaces table contains a list of values like

create table salesforce.unprocessed.namespace_list (namespace varchar(1024));
insert into salesforce.unprocessed.namespace_list (namespace) values ('SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.PRODUCT2', 'SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.ACCOUNTTEAMMEMBER', 'SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.USERROLE')


I’m pretty sure you can’t iterate over an array using a FOR loop. You should use a cursor rather than an array

Ok, fair enough. I can't figure out how to make this work at all then.

First of all for using dynamic table names in query , you should use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.
Second thing is to use Cursor for loop.
You probably need these changes :

USE EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

USING keyword for placeholders.

Cursor for iteration.
 FOR rec IN cur DO
 BEGIN
   -- Dynamically execute the query for each table name
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
       'INSERT INTO salesforce.unprocessed.job_logs
        SELECT ?, CURRENT_DATE(), 
               (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM IDENTIFIER(?) ), 
               (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM IDENTIFIER(?) )'
       USING rec.namespace, rec.namespace, rec.namespace;
     result := 'Success';
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       result := 'Error processing namespace: ' || rec.namespace || ' - ' || SQLERRM();
   END;
 END;

END LOOP;


For getting initial cursor data, you can use something like this.
cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT namespace FROM namespaces_table;


I tried reproducing your issue, I assume IDENTIFIER(?) would be the table names like SALESFORCE.UNPROCESSED.ACCOUNTTEAMMEMBER etc.
you can just use namespace instead of using IDENTIFIER.
FOR record IN cursor DO
        namespace := record.namespace;

and you can print the query that is getting generated to debug like below
RETURN 'Generated Query: ' || query;

I have used sample tables and the procedure worked fine
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_daily_job()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    namespace STRING;
    cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT namespace FROM namespace_list;
    query TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR record IN cursor DO
        namespace := record.namespace;
        query := 'INSERT INTO job_logs2 (namespace, rundate, distinct_count, id_count) ' ||
                 'SELECT ''' || namespace || ''', CURRENT_DATE(), ' ||
                 '(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM ' || namespace || '), ' ||
                 '(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ' || namespace || ')';
        RETURN 'Generated Query: ' || query;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query;
    END FOR;
    RETURN 'Success';
END;
$$;

Insert query that got generated from the procedure is as below and it runs OK:
 INSERT INTO job_logs2 (namespace, rundate, distinct_count, id_count)
 SELECT 'TEST.TEST.PRODUCT2', CURRENT_DATE(), (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM TEST.TEST.PRODUCT2), (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM TEST.TEST.PRODUCT2) ;

